# If statement to change css position on a page

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to duplicate the city thing on this website

http://www.blueacorn.com/

Im just trying to get the buildings falling down thing to work right now, but im having some trouble. I have the code working to bring a div down from outside a viewport down to in the view port with this code.

This first part is attached to a button with an id of #clicky

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#clicky').bind('click', slideIt);
});
```

This second part is the function that actually brings the div down.

```
function slideIt() {
    $('#thing').animate(
    { top: "+=600px"}, 3000);
};
```

Now I dont want people constantly clicking the button and having it go down further. I want it so that when they click another button, different divs come down and the ones that were there before go up just like in the city. So I was thinking to put an if statement, but Im not sure if that is even possible. The code I have thus far is this. Its also not working haha.

```
if ($('#thing').css('top') === '600px') {
    function slideIt() {
    $('#thing').animate(
    { top: "-=600px"}, 3000);
};
```

}

Im fairly certain the syntax is completely wrong. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try adding a fiddle on jsfiddle.net

And also try putting the if block inside the function.

Comment: Alright Ill do that right now.

Comment: I made a JS fiddle with a few different things. Still need to make the button unclickable after its in the final state, what do you guys think?

http://jsfiddle.net/AtY9m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things...
 1. just use a static final top value, it's simpler.
 2. when the button is clicked, you can unbind the clicky element so it's no longer clickable.

```
function slideIt() {
    $('#clicky').unbind('click');
    $('#thing').animate(
    { top: "0px"}, 3000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that.

```
function slideIt() {
    if($('#thing').hasClass('running')) {
        return;
    }    
    $('#thing').addClass('running').animate(
    { top: "+=600px"}, 3000);
};
```